# Как правильно скомпилировать исходники AVR911?

Tags: c++, avr

Помогите собрать исходники AVR911 - программатора микроконтроллеров AVR через bootloader. [Исходники](https://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en591218) скачаны с официального сайта Microchip, т.е. должны собираться без проблем. Но при создании проекта в VisualStudio 2019 и компиляции проекта вылезает много ошибок. Видимо я собираю их не в том IDE, или это нужно делать через командную строку, чего я ранее не делал.
Подскажите, как правильно собрать исходники, чтоб получить исполняемый файл. Всё это мне нужно для последующей корректировки исходников для использования программатора совместно с интерфейсом RS485.

Comment: при чем сдесь `IDE`? Как я вижу там есть `Makefile.win`, который, очевидно, и отвечает за сборку под винду. Ну а теперь вопрос по существу: а `make` то у вас стоит?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch Возможно и стоит, а как проверить?

Comment: При задании в командной строке 'make' появляется сообщение - "make" не является внутренней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: сначала разберитесь с инструментами (make, g++ и прочее), а потом приступайте к сборке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На форуме [РадиоКот](https://radiokot.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=125653&sid=eff1a27c8fbac7c23bdee3639bc3a273) выяснил, что этот проект собирается в среде разработки Dev-C++. Скачал её [отсюда](https://www.filehorse.com/download-dev-c/), установил. Открыл из исходников проект AVROSP, добавил в файл `AVRInSystemProg.cpp` строку `#include <time.h>`, удалил из файла `XMLparser.hpp` лишнее `XMLFile::` и проект успешно собрался